# Get length of array in object with unknown key

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to get length of the array in this object:

```
obj = {'2012-08-08':[1,2,5,8]}
```

I understand we can get length like this:

```
obj['2012-08-08'].length
```

But if it is not known the name of the key how we get the length of the array?

Say I have a loop:

```
_.each(dates, function(date){
     //each date is like the above javascript object, how to  get the length of the array?

})
```

Comment: This is beginning to feel like a lost battle, but still: that is *not* a JSON object.

Comment: Using variable names is a BAD idea. Leave variables for data and make structure easily predictable. Something like `{date:'2012-08-08', values:[1,2,5,8]}` will do the trick better.

Comment: That looks like underscore.js to me, not jQuery. If you've actually aliased jQuery to `_`, then please switch the tag back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `date` parameter in your call to `each`. Just call `date.length`.

Comment: You can do a `for` loop or use `each` again.